# Regex negative lookbehind in R

Tags: r, regex, negative-lookbehind

I'm trying to do a regex in stringr for a negative lookbehind in R.

So basically, I have a text data that looks something like this :

```
See item 7 Management's Discussion and Analysis. BlahBlahBlah. Item 7 Management's Discussion and Analysis. BlahBlahBlah. Item 8 Financial Statements and Supplementary Data.
```

I want to select everything from the "Item 7" right after the "blahblahblah." sentence to "Item 8-Financial Statements and Supplementary Data"

So I want

```
Item 7 Management's Discussion and Analysis. BlahBlahBlah. Item 8 Financial Statements and Supplementary Data.
```

which is everything except for the sentence that contains "see item 7 Management's Discussion and Analysis"

Right now, I'm working with this code:

```
(?<!see)Item 7(.*?)Item 8
```

But it's not returning what i want.

My logic is to not look at sentences that contain the word "see" followed by "item 7 Management's Discussion and Analysis" but it doesn't seem to be working.

https://regex101.com/r/yF7aQ1/3

Is there a way I can implement this negative lookbehind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you are implementing it in R, `.*(?<!See) (item 7 .*)` works with `sub`, just be careful with the space after the see and the letter case which you can ignore with `ignore.case` parameter.

```
sub(".*(?<!See) (item 7 .*)", "\\1", s, ignore.case = T, perl = T)

# [1] "Item 7 Management's Discussion and Analysis. BlahBlahBlah. Item 8 Financial Statements and Supplementary Data."
```

Another alternative:

```
sub(".*(?=(?<!See) ?item 7)", "", s, ignore.case = T, perl = T)
# [1] "Item 7 Management's Discussion and Analysis. BlahBlahBlah. Item 8 Financial Statements and Supplementary Data."
```

With `str_extract_all()` from `stringr` package, which doesn't seem to provide an `ignore.case` option, you can use `[Ii]` to ignore the case:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(s, "(?<!See )[Ii]tem 7(.*)")
# [1] "Item 7 Management's Discussion and Analysis. BlahBlahBlah. Item 8 Financial Statements and Supplementary Data."
```

Comment: Oh! Sorry! I forgot to add that I'm using stringr to do it.

Comment: So str_extract_all(text, regex("(?<!see)Item 7(.*?)Item 8"), ignore_case =TRUE))

Comment: Yes you can. See the update. It doesn't seem like your regex matches your desired output. I am following the output from your original question.

Comment: Great! I'll try that. And ignore.case works for str_extract I just have to put it like this: str_extract_all(text, regex("(?<!See )Item 7(.*)"), ignore_case =TRUE))

Comment: So if I'm understanding your regex correctly, its excluding any sentence that has the word "see" and "item 7" in it?

Comment: For the `sub`. It is excluding everything before `item 7` except `item 7` is preceded by `see`, and for `str_extract_all`, it is extracting everything after `item 7` except it is preceded by `see`, which are the same thing.

Comment: Thats awesome. Your help is going to do me wonders. 

If I include this command: (.*?) inside this (?<!See ) line, 
so that it looks like this: (?<!See (.*?)), would this work too?

Comment: So the above case would be where the preceding sentence has "See item 7" along with some other stuff. 
So "See item 7 Management's Discussion and Analysis blahblahblah."

Comment: Negative look behind syntax must have fixed length, that won't work, but you can try to move `(.*?)` after the `(?<! )` group. Don't quite know what you are trying to achieve though.

Comment: My goal is to filter out sentences where "item 7" and "see" are both included. 
That is, I want to extract everything that from "Item 7 Management's Discussion and Analysis" to "Item 8 Financial Statements and Supplementary Data"  without including the sentences with "item 7" and "see"